# Jquery PathName Regex Changing Background

Tags: jquery, regex, path

i'm just starting to learn jquery and i wanted to know if i'm doing it right.
here is my code

```
 var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg','6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg'];
if (window.location == 'http://localhost:81/ci/login') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("public/images/login_4.jpg")');
} else if(window.location == 'http://localhost:81/ci/index.php/login') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../public/images/login_4.jpg")');
}else {
    $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(public/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
}
```

what the first block does is check if  the location is the same as the given string
the problem with that is that if the url looks like this
`http://localhost:81/ci/login?` or `http://localhost:81/ci/login#`

the code fails... I know there is a regex solution for that. What do you think fellas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any regex for this, you can just use `indexOf()`

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('http://localhost:81/ci/login') != -1)
{....}
else if(window.location.href.indexOf('http://localhost:81/ci/index.php/login' != -1)
{....}
```

Or better yet, combine them into this for more portable code:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('login') != -1)
```

Comment: If you want to port this code to another domain (not localhost), it would be smart to use the second version as you can copy the javascript as is.

Comment: the first time i tried the 2nd code you gave it doesn't work, i  did some googling and added the `toString` method before the `indexOf`

Comment: You're right, forgot that location is an object, href is a string.

Comment: one problem i found again is that of `login/` with a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is inefficient and should be avoided for simple cases like this.

Try this instead:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://localhost:81/ci/login') == 0) {
     ...
} ...
```

If you insist on using a regex (certainly a handy tool to start learning) you can do the same thing like so:

```
if (/^http:\/\/localhost:81\/ci\/login/.test(window.location.href)) {
     ...
} ...
```

The caret ^ symbol marks the start of the string being matched - without that, this test would be true even if the pattern appeared in the middle of a string.  Since the slashes mark the start and end of the regex, all slashes in the pattern must be escaped.

Comment: thank you! i appreciate it.. i'll take your advice into consideration. thanks much!